# display html pages from WEB-INF in java

Tags: java, html

I'm a begginer in java web. I am trying to solve this problem but it does not work. Please give me a full solution. What I need to add or change to make html pages from WEB-INF display(in this case search.html) .

[image]

Here is my servlet code and login.js

@WebServlet("/dispatcher")

public class DispatcherServlet extends HttpServlet {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    resp.setContentType("application/json");
    String action = req.getParameter("action");

    try{
    switch(action){
    case "login": 
        AuthenticationActionsHandler authentication = new AuthenticationActionsHandler();
        sendResponse(resp, authentication.logIn(req) );
    break;
    case "registration":
        authentication = new AuthenticationActionsHandler();
        sendResponse(resp, authentication.registration(req) );
    break;
    case "getName": 
        if((Integer) req.getSession().getAttribute("Id") != null){
            UserActionsHandler user = new UserActionsHandler();
            sendResponse(resp, user.getName(req) );
        }
    break;
    case "logOut":
        authentication = new AuthenticationActionsHandler();
        sendResponse(resp, authentication.logOut(req) );            
    break;
    case "search": 
        ActionsHandler searchAction = new ActionsHandler();
        sendResponse(resp, searchAction.search(req) );
    break;
    case "saveRequest":
        ActionsHandler saveRequestAction = new ActionsHandler();
        sendResponse(resp, saveRequestAction.saveRequest(req) );
    break;
    case "showRequestedBooks":
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
        Integer userId = (Integer)session.getAttribute("Id");
        if(userId == null){
            JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
            result.put("authentication", false);
            sendResponse(resp, result);
        } else{
            ActionsHandler showRequestedBooks = new ActionsHandler();
            sendResponse(resp, showRequestedBooks.showRequestedItems(req) );
        }
    break;

    }
}catch(MissingParameterException e){
        sendErrorResponse(resp, e.getMissingParams());
}
}

public void sendResponse(HttpServletResponse resp, JSONArray resultJson ){
    PrintWriter out;
    try {
        out = resp.getWriter();
        out.println(resultJson);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}





$("#login").click(function(){
var hashPassword = hex_md5($("#password").val());
var requestData = {
        username: $('#username').val(),
        password: hashPassword,
        action: "login",
};
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "/Library/dispatcher",
    data : requestData,
 }).done(
         function(responseData){
             if(responseData.error){
                 console.log(responseData.error);
                 $('#unsuccess').show();
             }
             else{
                 if(responseData.success){
                    // window.location.href = "/Library/search.html";
                     window.location.href = "/WEB-INF/search.html";
                 }
                 else{
                     $('#unsuccess').show();
                 }
             }
        });
});
```

Comment: you shouldn't put html file in web-inf. your html and js file should be in your WebContent folder or one of its sub folders. web-inf is hidden for the client side, only server side can see it.

Comment: WEB-INF is a sub-folder of WebContent ;D

Comment: @YosefY This folder can be hidden, but it depends of the server configuration.

Comment: WEB-INF is an internal folder for the java web server. it is defaultly hidden, so when i wrote "WebContent folder or one of its sub folders" I thought WEB-INF excluded... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding SearchServlet

```
@WebServlet("/search")
public class SearchServlet extends HttpServlet {
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{

        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/search.html").forward(request, response);
   }
}
```

And in your DispatcherServlet, if login succeeds, redirect user to search servlet by calling `response.sendRedirect("/search")`

Comment: Dear thoitbk I've added a new servlet and response.sendRedirect("/search") to my dispatcherServlet, but it doesn't work. Should I make changes in my js code, becouse after pressing login button I couldn't refer to search.html page (seems  window.location.href = "/WEB-INF/search.html"; doesn't work ).

Comment: try `window.location.href = "/search"`

Answer (score 0):

instead we can JSP and HTML files place it in a seperate folder parallel to WEB-INF...WEB-INF is private folder.. if I am not wrong...Also Servlets are placed inside WEB-INF\classes and they need compilation for every modifications done where as JSp and HTML files modifications are recognised by container automatically

Comment: Dear Duke thanks for your reply. I replace search.html in WEB-INF, becouse I want prevent direct access to this page. At first users must go to login page and through it reach to search page.

Answer (score 0):

change extension to jsp, move it to WebContent and add at the beginning the verification that the user is logged in (you can put for that something in the HttpSession). If not redirect him to the login page...

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment you want to redirect the users into login page first. For this we can choose that html file as a Welcome file inside web.xml(Deployment Descriptor)

See below

```
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>login.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

After authentication is proper then we should allow them into search.html file by using sendRedirect.

Answer (score 0):

This is [not possible by specification page 70](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-2.4-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/servlet-2_4-fr-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1431011300_1d44c7c588b33a09053d6862bc0fba9e).

> The WEB-INF node is not part of the public
>   document tree of the application. No file contained in the WEB-INF directory may
>   be served directly to a client by the container.

By servlet-3.0 its possible to serve a file in `WEB-INF/classes/resources/` but i think this is bad practice.

Sorry